# Why does my banner appear under my main view?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm developing an app, however I'm running into a small visual glitch on this page in which the banner appears underneath main view.

[image: bugged ui image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzogQ.png

content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.ben.trimpsapp.DrawerMenu">


    <RelativeLayout
..../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".CalcActivity">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_drawer_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/content_perk_calc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer_menu"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_menu_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity.java

```
package com.example.ben.trimpsapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Ben on 07/07/2016.
 */
public class CalculatorActivity extends MainActivity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perk_calc);


        EditText editText;
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        button.setText(String.valueOf("kek"));
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calcMain();
            }
        });
        menu();
    }

    public void calcMain() {


        double cost = 1;
        double multiplier = 2;
        int count = 0;

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        ;
        double helium = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

        while (helium >= cost) {

            helium = helium - cost;
            cost = cost * multiplier;
            count++;

        }

        int remainder = (int) helium;

        final TextView coordinatedCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView0);
        coordinatedCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        final TextView remainderCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        remainderCount.setText(String.valueOf(remainder));

    }


}
```

For context the `menu();` runs the standard android draw menu, with the modification in that it is a method to be run, rather than being done in the `onCreate();`

I don't believe I have any methods besides this that modify layout/appearance yet.

If any other code or information is needed for a solution, I am happy to supply it.

EDITS:

margin bug from suggested solution

[image]

layout underneath bug from attempted solution

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `activity.xml`, you never set the perk calc layout to be below the menu. I have changed some of your code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".CalcActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <include
                layout="@layout/app_bar_drawer_menu"
                android:id="@+id/drawer_menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar">

            <include
                layout="@layout/content_perk_calc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer_menu"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_menu_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**
So I checked some of my other default code for layouts and figured out another way that may work. I surrounded your layout in a FrameLayout and put your menu layout inside of an AppBarLayout. I usually use this when I am using Android Toolbars so I think this should work. Also, please note that your `content.xml` file has width and height set to "match_parent". This could also be the source of the problem.

**Edit #2:**
In this case, there was only one line of code missing in the FrameLayout for content_perk_calc. The code that was missing was: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`. This made it so his layout was laid out below the bar on the top of the screen. The code has been edited and placed in the code above.

Comment: ideally, this seems like it should make sense, however, no, it doesn't seem to fix the problem, no changes visible

Comment: Try what I just changed and also try changing your height to wrap_content in `content.xml`.

Comment: the edit proved useful, added the changes, fixed the main issue, however causes a large margin on the banner, removing `fitsSystemWindow` fixes this, however then the main layout sits underneath the draw menu banner, in the process of trying to fix this however, I thought it worth posting an update

Comment: Try getting rid of the `android:layout_marginTop="35dp"` in your include code for the `content_perk_calc` layout.

Comment: That was the first thing I did, my bad for not sharing

Comment: Will you post an image of this? I might still be able to figure out what's causing it

Comment: they're in the main post :)

Comment: I just noticed I never closed the <FrameLayout UI Element in that code... I guess that could be the problem :P (I changed the above code again)

Comment: nope, I caught that as well, should amend your answer though, in case we work it out, wouldn't do any good for an accepted answer to have missing code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117270/discussion-between-ben-bowen-and-theanonymous010).